# Making a scalar within a scale in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have weather temperature for the next few days. I want to map all values no matter how much to a scale of `{0,1,2,3,4}`

For this I am trying:

```
let scale = Math.round((todayTemp / maxTemp) * 5) - 1
```

With

```
  markersIcons[0] = 'blue'
  markersIcons[1] = 'purple'
  markersIcons[2] = 'green'
  markersIcons[3] = 'yellow'
  markersIcons[4] = 'red'
```

and

```
markersIcons[scale]
```

I have undefined results. So much unpredictable results: {-1,5,...?}

I am not sure why is this, mathematically I am sure of the banal formulae.

Comment: how much is `maxTemp`? do you have a `minTemp`?

Comment: What is unpredicable on `-1` value (result when `todayTemp = 0`)? What if `maxTemp` will be 0?

Comment: @pavel you are right, my bad. I will check that but I think "I thought" it is very unprobable in my case tapping the weather API which is sourced by accurate sensors. anyway,

Comment: @NinaScholz in an array of minTemps, maxTemp is the maximum.

Comment: ok I missed that Math.round(1/10) rounds to 0 which yields -1. I am verifying why 5 is possible though

Comment: I am sorry, I missed the possibility of negative values altogether. deleting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hand over a minimum value (inclusive) and a maximum value (exclusive) and the actual to get a color.

```js
const
    COLORS = ['blue', 'purple', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'],
    getColor = (min, max, value) => COLORS[Math.floor(COLORS.length * (value - min) / (max - min))];

console.log(getColor(-10, 40, -10));
console.log(getColor(-10, 40, 0));
console.log(getColor(-10, 40, 10));
console.log(getColor(-10, 40, 20));
console.log(getColor(-10, 40, 30));
console.log(getColor(-10, 40, 39));
```

Comment: I like this, I though of the scale for also negative values, you are right. I only have to fix division by zero. accepting this